# Eclipse Kepler shows a error in a dtd plugin file

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem using:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
```

Shows a error in a XML:

```
referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Data/helios/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.standard.schemas_1.0.700.v201304171716.jar!/dtds/strict.dtd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."  applicationContext-hibernate.xml    /main/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring line 1  XML Problem
```

This error is annoying because it marks the project folder as having errors and this means I can't see other errors real errors or compilation errors.

This web page shows which seems the folder which is causing the error:

[Java2 Download](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipsewststandardschemas10401v201108151912jar.htm)

Is there a workaround for this?

Eclipse screenshot:

[image: Eclipse]

[image: Strict.dtd]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to edit the questioned    `strict.dtd`   ? Look up line 81. Or post the surrounding code here so we can see what eclipse is angry about.

```
<!--================== Imported Names =================-->
<!-- Feature Switch for frameset documents -->
<!ENTITY % HTML.Frameset "IGNORE">

<!ENTITY % ContentType "CDATA"
    -- media type, as per [RFC2045] <===line 81 in my installation
    -->
```

Comment: Looks exactly like mine. I doubted a corrupted     `.jar`    
Then look up the    `applicationContext-hibernate.xml`    somewhere around the 81st line.

Comment: Is weird because i have replace it with the same jar but of a newer Eclipse edition from a fellow teammate but nothing happens neither.